# How to take the output of method and pass to another method in JAVA?

Tags: java, methods

I am new to java and still learning the concepts. From my code below I have two methods one for children and one for adults.  I want to output the total number of people, so I would like a third method (calc_total) which would take the output of calc_children and calc_adults.  I can't figure out how to do this, can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
public class Testcalc {

    public int calc_children( int aBoys, int aGirls) {
        int a_num_children = aBoys + aGirls;

        return a_num_children;
    }   

    public int calc_adults( int aMen, int bWomen) {
        int a_num_adults = aMen + bWomen;

        return a_num_adults;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Testcalc calc1 = new Testcalc();

        int aChildren = calc1.calc_children(4,6);
        int bAdults = calc1.calc_adults(5,8);

        System.out.println("Total Children " + aChildren);
        System.out.println("Total Adults " + bAdults);  
    }                               
}
```

Comment: Exactly the same as your previous two methods...

Comment: Why not just call System.out.println("Total People " + (bAdults + aChildren)); instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Testcalc
{

    public class Testcalc {

    public int calc_children( int aBoys, int aGirls) {
        int a_num_children = aBoys + aGirls;

        return a_num_children;
    }   

    public int calc_adults( int aMen, int bWomen) {
        int a_num_adults = aMen + bWomen;

        return a_num_adults;
    }
    public int calc_total(int a,int b)
    {
return a+b;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Testcalc calc1 = new Testcalc();

      int aChildren = calc1.calc_children(4,6);
     int bAdults = calc1.calc_adults(5,8);
    int total=calc1.calc_total(aChildren,bAdults);

        System.out.println("Total Children " + aChildren);
        System.out.println("Total Adults " + bAdults);  
    System.out.println("Total" + total);

    }                               
}
```

Pass the variables "aChildren" and "bAdults" to the new function which returns their sum.The returned value will be assigned to the variable "total".Simply print the variable "total".

Answer (score 0):

```
public int myMethod(){
  return 5;
}

public void myAge(int age){
  System.out.println(age);
}

//You can do:
myAge(myMethod());
```

In your case:

```
public int calcTotal(int children, int adults){
 return children + adults;
}


//You can do:
calcTotal(calc_children(5,10),calc_adults(9,12));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, you already have this kind of method, add this one to `Testcalc` .

```
public int calc_total( int totalMen, int totalWomen) {
    int a_num_total= totalMen+ totalWomen;

    return a_num_total;
    }
```

Then :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Testcalc calc1 = new Testcalc();

int aChildren = calc1.calc_children(4,6);
int bAdults = calc1.calc_adults(5,8);
int total = calc1.calc_total(aChildren,bAdults);

System.out.println("Total Children " + aChildren);
System.out.println("Total Adults " + bAdults);  
System.out.println("Grand total " + total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a third method like you mention, `calc_total`, and just like your other two methods, it can also take two `ints` as parameters. Then in your main file, you can pass the results of `calc_children` and `calc_adults` as the arguments passed to your new method `calc_total`. Think about it. Use `aChildren` and `bAdults`

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like this:

```
  public int calc_total(){
    Testcalc calc1 = new Testcalc();

   int total= calc1.calc_children(4,6) + calc1.calc_adults(5,8);

   return total;
 }
```